# Are the wp entries in these URL's legitimate?

Tags: urls

I apologize I know nothing about WordPress I'm just looking for some help. I was wondering if the `wp-admin` and `#wpbody-content` parameters in these URL's are normal and safe? They are from links in an email, but aren't normally there when you go to the site direct.

The top image is the URL going to the site direct, middle are what was in the email, and bottom is what the URL is after clicking one of the links.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Whatever plugin is generating these emails, that's whats adding the parameters.  The `/wp-admin/` links are taking you to the WP Dashboard, which you need credentials for and the `#wpbody-content` is an `id="wpbody-content"` attribute, probably on the `<div>` tag the has that content. What this will do is jump down to that section when the page loads. Nothing I see here makes me think you have anything to be concerned about - just looks as though whatever plugin is sending you these emails is trying to make your life easier by sending you to specific places on the site.

Answer (score 3):

Those are valid links to approve a comment, trash it, or mark it as spam, and a link to view moderated comments. The `#wpbody-content` part is just an anchor so that the page scrolls to a certain point when you visit it.

There's nothing inherently harmful or unsafe about those links, but whether or not they should be included in a given email depends entirely on the context of that email and who it's sent to, and you haven't provided that information.

Your last screenshot suggests that you're attempting to access these links while you are not logged in, so you're being redirected to a log in page, which would be the expected behaviour. Normally that would be `/wp-login.php`, but you appear to be running some kind of membership plugin with a custom login page, which is a normal thing a plugin like that might do.